# How to configure @nuxtjs/auth with Auth0

Tags: vue.js, authentication, nuxt.js, auth0

I created a Nuxt application that uses Auth0 as the login provider. When you log in, you get redirected to the callback page and then the auth module takes over and saves the login information in the state.
All works perfectly in Dev mode, but as soon as I generate code for production, the auth module no longer reacts to the callback and you are not logged in.
Generating in target server or static has no effect.
I'm set to mode=universal.
I tried to enable SSR or specifically disable it, to no effect.
I'm using

"nuxt": "^2.15.4"

"@nuxtjs/auth": "^4.9.1",

I've been fighting this thing for a week, and I've seen numerous threads that talk about this, but no one provided a solution.
Is this really a problem that was not dealt with in Nuxt? That pretty much kills the usefulness of the platform if it can't handle auth in production...
Does anyone have a way to solve this?

I'm willing to post my code, if it will help resolve this.

EDIT: here is my nuxt.config.js file:

```js
export default {
    mode: 'universal',
    target: 'server',
    css: [],
    plugins: [
        { src: '~/plugins/vue-debounce.js' },
        { src: '~/plugins/modal-popup.js', ssr: false },
        { src: '~/plugins/editor.js', ssr: false },
    ],
    components: true,
    buildModules: ['@nuxtjs/eslint-module', '@nuxtjs/fontawesome'],
    fontawesome: {
        component: 'fa',
        suffix: true,
        icons: {
            solid: ['faCaretDown', 'faCaretRight', 'faCaretLeft'],
            regular: ['faFileAlt'],
        },
    },
    modules: [
        '@nuxtjs/axios',
        '@nuxtjs/auth',
    ],
    axios: {
        baseURL: 'http://localhost:9000/api/',
        headers: {
            common: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
            },
        },
    },
    auth: {
        strategies: {
            auth0: {
                domain: '<my domain>.eu.auth0.com',
                client_id: '<client id>',
                audience: 'https://<my domain>.eu.auth0.com/api/v2/',
            },
        },
        redirect: {
            callback: '/callback/',
            logoutRedirectUri: '/login'
        },
    },
    build: {
        transpile: [],
    },
}
```

Comment: `mode` is deprecated, so there is that. Could you please post your `nuxt.config.js` please? Also, do you want full static or SPA only for the production build?

Comment: I added the config file, see above. Re the target, I don't really care. I'm just trying to make it work. Truth be told, I haven't fully considered the differences between the two. I'm still too early in the project for that to make a difference. Does this have a significance to the solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.
I had implemented a non-standard header in Axios, like so:

```
axios: {
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:9000/api/',
    headers: {
        common: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            authentication: "<UUID code>"
        },
    },
}
```

I did it as a temporary way to secure the communication with the server, until I had Auth0 running, and I forgot to remove it.

As soon as I got rid of this header, it started working as expected.
I'm not sure why this would cause the fact that it worked in developer mode and not in generated code, but removing the line made it work in both.

Comment: Glad that you found out what was the issue! It was working locally maybe the security is a bit more flexible locally than on production.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a repo that I've created that explains in depth how to setup the most setup auth0 connection flow: https://github.com/kissu/so-nuxt-docs-theme-auth-auth0

Please pay attention to the `README.md` and then, check how it works with your `auth` setup. Here is my section

`nuxt.config.js`

```js
auth: {
  redirect: {
    callback: "/",
    home: "/",
    login: "/login",
    logout: "/"
  },
  localStorage: false,
  strategies: {
    local: false,
    auth0: {
      domain: process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
      clientId: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
      scope: ['openid', 'profile', 'offline_access'],
      accessType: 'offline',
      responseType: 'code',
      grantType: 'authorization_code',
      codeChallengeMethod: 'S256',
    }
  },
},
```

As for the target, if you're limiting the access to your app straight from the beginning, the best way to go is still

```js
target: 'static',
ssr: false,
```

That way, it will not require any NodeJS server and will be SPA only. Indeed, there is no need to generate protected pages (by auth0) since the guy needs to be logged-in. And, it will not generate them because of the way `@nuxt/auth` works.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Thanks for the effort, but I'm afraid not. 
Your project successfully handles the callback after the login. However, since you used the @nuxt/content-theme-docs interface, I find it hard to find the parallel to my project. I tried comparing  your Package.json and nuxt.config.js to mine, and I found that the only relevant differences were the fact that you use @nuxtjs/auth-next' where I used '@nuxtjs/auth'. So I switched to that in both and copied the auth configuration from yours to mine.
When I generate the site and run it statically, I still get the same behavior.

Comment: The docs theme is nothing special and can totally be ditched, just let it there since it's one of my projects and I didn't bother removing it. `@nuxt/auth-next` is the v5 of the auth module and pretty much the one that should be used. The other part is the configuration part on Auth0 itself and I did my best to explain the steps that I followed but this is probably what is missing in your case.

Comment: Your explanation was perfect. I got it working in nothing flat. Problem is my version is still not working, even though it's now configured in the exact same way. 
Here's what I see in the console when I get to the callback page after I log in:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://<my domain>.eu.auth0.com/oauth/token' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field user_id is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
VM480:1 POST https://<my domain>.eu.auth0.com/oauth/token net::ERR_FAILED

Maybe there's a clue there?

Comment: This one is a CORS issue, so a purely backend (= auth0 dashboard) issue, are you sure you whitelisted `http://localhost:3000` there and do not have any typo or alike? Double check your `.env` variables too.

Comment: I did. The config file is identical to yours and in your project, with the same configuration, it works. So the Auth0 configuration is not the problem, and I haven't done anything with my backend. It's failing against Auth0. I'm guessing that it assumes it's logged in once it gets to the callback page and since the auth token was not saved, it fails the call. I think the failure is before this call.
Strangely, the developer tools network tab shows no calls at all. Even the login call is not shown there.

Comment: Well, I created a Nuxt project from scratch, and added nothing to it but the Auth and it worked for me, using the same configuration. I don't understand it. I guess I'll have to move my files to this new project and see when if it still works...

Comment: Maybe another package in your `package.json` is causing the issue?

Comment: I finally recreated the project from scratch and added stuff in one bit at a time. See my posted solution below for the explanation. Thank you very much for your help. I appreciate it enormously.